# ASP.NET MVC attaches current path to remote Url Request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to display a remote web app in a modal div.  All of this code was already created in an Asp.net webforms app.  I am trying to reproduce it in an MVC App using the code that is already written.  It uses Javascript to create an iFrame to display the application in a modal popup.  The problem that I am having is that at some point (I can't figure out where or when after stepping through the code), MVC concatenates the current window location with the RequestedUrl and I end up with the following error:

[image]

The function that creates the iFrame in the popup is:

```
function CreateModalPopupHtmlElementsExitWithClickSave(ModalBoxDivObject, TargetDivName, TargetSource, TargetWidth, TargetHeight, ButtonText, SpanText) {

    var iframe = CreateHtmlElement('div', { 'id': 'iframeDiv' });
    iframe.innerHTML = "<iframe width='" + TargetWidth + "' height='" + TargetHeight + "' id='iframeModalPopup' style='border-width:1px; border-color:#333; background:#FFF; border-style:solid;' src=" + encodeURIComponent(TargetSource) + "' scrolling='yes' marginwidth='1' marginheight='1' frameborder='1'/>";
    ModalBoxDivObject.appendChild(iframe);

    var div = CreateHtmlElement('div', { 'id': 'CloseDiv' });
    div.innerHTML = "<div style='text-align: center;'><span id='txt' style='font-family:arial;background-color: White;'>" + SpanText + "</span><input type='button' onclick='HideModalDivExitWithClickSave();' value='" + ButtonText + "' id='HideModalDivButton' /></div>"

    ModalBoxDivObject.appendChild(div);
}
```

The Target is set with the following function:

```
   function ShowManagementdDiv(imageTypeID, Guid, selectedYear) {
        debugger;
        var TargetWidth = 950;
        var TargetHeight = 670;
        bModalPopupActivated = true; window.clearTimeout(t);
        DisplayModalDivExitWithClickSave('box', TargetWidth, TargetHeight, 'http://localhost/PECIMS/DocumentManagement.aspx?eid=' + imageTypeID + '&Edx=' + Guid + '&y=' + selectedYear, 'Close', 'Click to close window.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    }
```

The target is set correctly when it hits the function that sets up the iFrame:

[image]

When it hits the function the (TargetSource) is the correct Url, but when the popup displays, MVC has added the current window location to it.  How do I remove the default web path from the RequestedUrl?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The iframe source is missing a `/`... should be `http://`

Comment: Can we see how you assign the value to `TargetSource`?

Comment: If you are using Url.Content this will fail as you seem to be redirecting the source to an application outside of the root url.

Comment: I updated the question show how the target is set.  Let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks!

Comment: @Irb - Url.Content does not exist anywhere in my project.